# Vuejs Axios data not showing

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios, laravel-5.6

The problem of not showing information is delayed in fetching , i need any help for this problem.

```
        <h1>@{{message}}</h1>

        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-10"><h3 class="panel-title">Experience</h3></div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 text-right">
                        <button class="btn btn-success">Ajouter</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="panel-body" >

                <ul class="list-group">
                    <li class="list-group-item" v-for="experience in experiences" >
                        <div class="pull-right">
                            <button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Editer</button>
                        </div>
                        <h3>@{{experience.titre}}</h3>
                        <p>@{{experience.body}}</p>
                        <small>@{{experience.debut}} - @{{experience.fin}}</small>
                    </li>

                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
```

**Vuejs**

```
<script src="{{asset('js/vue.js')}}"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script>
     var app = new Vue({
       el: '#app',
       data: {
         message: 'Nawfal Kharbouch',
         experiences:[]
       },
       methods:{
        getExperiences:function(){
            axios.get('http://localhost:8080/getexperiences').then(response=>{
                this.experiences=response.data;
                console.log(this.experiences);
            }).catch(function(error){
                console.log('erros : ',error);
            })  
        }
       },
       mounted:function(){
        this.getExperiences();
        console.log(this.experiences);
        }
    })
</script>
```

The problem of not showing information is delayed in fetching , i need any help for this problem.
//console Google Chrome

```
[__ob__: Observer]
vue.js:8553 You are running Vue in development mode.
Make sure to turn on production mode when deploying for production.
See more tips at https://vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html
backend.js:1  vue-devtools  Detected Vue v2.5.16 
5:171 (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}, __ob__: Observer];
```

//picture [view vide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clUdz.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not pass "this" inside a promise, you need to add "this" to a variable.

Exemple:

```js
var app = new Vue({
       el: '#app',
       data: {
         message: 'Nawfal Kharbouch',
         experiences:[]
       },
       methods:{
        var self = this;
        getExperiences:function(){
            axios.get('http://localhost:8080/getexperiences').then(response=>{
                self.experiences=response.data;
                console.log(self.experiences);
            }).catch(function(error){
                console.log('erros : ',error);
            })  
        }
       },
        mounted:function(){
        this.getExperiences();
        console.log(this.experiences);
         }
    })
```

Comment: When I say the method it gives error.That's right.https://stackoverflow.com/a/51634629/10636297

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using this directly you need to pass it to a variable.

```js
methods:{
        getExperiences:function(){
        var vm = this
            axios.get('http://localhost:8080/getexperiences').then(response=>{
                vm.experiences=response.data;
                console.log(vm.experiences);
            }).catch(function(error){
                console.log('erros : ',error);
            })  
        }
       },
```